# How to reload http window.opener from https popup?

Tags: javascript, http, https, cross-domain, xss

I have an http window which opens a secure popup to submit a form to a third party web site. After the popup is closed, I would like to reload the opener so that it reflects the results of the form submission.

Since the opener and the popup use different protocols (http and https), I can't do it in the straightforward way (window.opener.location.reload()). Is there another way? Do I have to venture into JSONP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is a super old question, but I found a better way to do this: [Cross-document messaging](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging):

```
$('a#popup').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    authenticationWindow = window.open($this.href, 'authenticationPopup');
});

window.addEventListener('message', function (evt) {
    // simplified, should check for matching event.origin
    if (event.data == 'OK' && event.origin == window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host) {
        authenticationWindow.close();
    }
});
```

While from the pop up (of course if you control it, at least the last page) you need this:

```
opener.postMessage('OK', window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host);
```

This will close the popup, and allows you to do other stuff as well, like update data via Ajax or reload the page.

Comment: NB: the event.origin must match the second paramenter of opener.postMessage

Answer (score 2):

Kludgy way: set timeout to check if opened popup was closed.

```
function checkClosed(){
    if(new_win.closed){
        alert('Window was closed');
    }
    else{
       window.setTimeout(checkClosed,1000);
    }
} 

new_win = window.open('about:blank');
window.setTimeout(checkClosed,1000);
```